# radio buttons not visible on woocommerce cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My radio buttons for shipping options on the woocommerce cart page (http://www.couponclippingworld.com/cart/) don't show when the page is first viewed or refreshed. [image]

However if someone clicks on one of the 4 shipping method texts the buttons show up. [image]

If the buyer proceeds to the checkout page (http://www.couponclippingworld.com/checkout/) the buttons are visible on this page.

I checked the CSS but I could not figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thx Greg

Answer (score 0):

It is because you wrap the input inside `<div class="tm-radio">` Remove that element as it is on checkout.

Also it works when you click an option because it sends an ajax request that replaces the content of your block with this:

```
<ul id="shipping_method">
        <li>
                            <input type="radio" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate"
 value="flat_rate"  class="shipping_method" />
                            <label for="shipping_method_0_flat_rate">Standard (Free)</label>
                        </li> etc.
```

However, if you want to style those buttons with css you need to add a width and a height to `.tm-radio`. Styling shipping radio buttons via css is not a good idea as it will never work perfectly across every mobile device and it can stop your customers checking out.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'll change it soon.

Comment: Thanks, i changed it in inspector and it worked, but how do I find the relevant file to change with sublime text editor? Where is it located? Thanks again

Comment: I'm guessing I need to find the relevant .php file so I can eliminate the <div class="tm-radio"> Is that correct? 

When I "inspect element" in my bowser and see the html how do i change the html? I think there must be a way to find the wordpress .php file from the html but I'm not able to figure it out.

Is that how i do it? Is there a better way? Tried looking it up online or in wordpress codex for about an hour. Not getting anywhere. I don't think I even know what to ask.

Comment: Ok simple question How do I remove it? Please help getting frustrated

Comment: @GregRobertson unfortunately that class can be anywhere depending on what plugins you are using. the only solution is to do a search in your folders for the word tm-radio . Notepad++ has search in folder function, but sublime has something similar too

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Ended up using drop down instead of radio buttons. Problem solved